# Returning records not found on a second self referencing table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have this tables

Tbllang: lname

Tbldata: id, title,parentid,lname

Sample Data:

Tbllang:
en
nl
ru
de

Tbldata
1 samuel 0 en
2 samuelde 1 de
3 elena 0 en

Parentid is 0 or equal to id. Basically i have same record in multiple languages and it is ok.

For Samuel, i have en and de already. I want to return ru and nl. For elena, i want nl, ru and de.

The following sql statement failed:

```
Select lname from tbllang where tbllang.lname<>tbldata.lname and (id=1 and parentid=1)
```

What am i missing?

Comment: what version of SQL are you using?

Comment: I am using Mysql mariadb

Comment: You should add a minimum sample data.

Comment: I have added few records for both tables.

Comment: Add  your sample data to the question so we understand the structure of your tables better

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to use the `[not] exists` operator:

```
SELECT lname
FROM   tbllange l
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   tbldata d
                   WHERE  l.lname = d.lname AND d.id = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect tbllang to have an ID column which is a foreign key in tbldata but you are not showing one. If there is then you could do an anti semi join.

```
select lname from tblland a left join tbldata b on a.id = b.parentid where b.parentID is null
```

This would give you all the rows in tbllang which dont have rows in tbldata